# Unable to place order - "Sorry, no quotes are available for this order at this time"

Tags: checkout, shipping, shipping-methods, shipping-address, error-message

Recently a store that I have used regularly had a whole revamp and I am trying to place an order for the first time since the site had the changes. When I proceed to checkout it asks for the shipping address which I have input as the exact same shipping address I have used on all other orders I have made on the Store. Not once did I ever have an issue with placing an order to the address but now when I select the address it displays the following message under the shipping methods section and gives no option to do anything else.

Shipping Methods

"Sorry, no quotes are available for this order at this time"

Screenshot - https://i.stack.imgur.com/fnUmW.jpg

I have also tried my old address, my parents address, my work address and none of them work. The item I am trying to order is limited time and will be removed from the store on August 31st. I really don't want to miss out on purchasing but I can't figure out what is preventing me from being able to proceed with ordering now.

I have sent three emails to the customer services team but have had no response in 2 weeks and its getting closer to the time were you can no longer order the item. Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This message is displayed when there are no shipping rates available. They either have no available shipping methods (for your address, in general, etc...) or some other bug in the shops checkout process causes that no shipping methods are available in this case.

As it sounds that you are a customer, the only thing you can really do is clearing your browser cache or use another browser to give it a second try. Also check your entered address again. If that doesn't work, it's up to the shop to fix that issue.

You can also test another address (in another state/country) and- another product if shipping methods are shown, to narrow down the problem to this specific product or this specific product category. This can help the customer service to get your issue fixed faster - although two weeks for your current emails isn't a good sign.

Testing out another account would also be an option. It sounds for me that they maybe migrated from Magento 1 to Magento 2. Migration can sometimes break accounts when done incorrectly or overseeing issues. If the account you are using is from the time before they revamped the shop, a new account could solve your issues. That said, the terms and conditions of many sites disallow multiple accounts per customer.

Maybe you will be lucky and the store will be generous due to the issues and extend the time the item is available if others also had the same issue.